# No Javascript provider error

Tags: grails

I imported a Grails 1.3.7 project into 'Sprint Source Tools Suite' (which uses Grails 2.2.3) and I keep getting the error:
    "Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: No javascript provider is configured"

I read a different post and the answer was to run: grails install-plugin prototype

But how do I do this in the IDE?

~Bill

Comment: I found that there is a way to access the Grails control panel and enter it there. I did that. But the error persists. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the grails jquery and resources plugin installed ?
A plugin may have been left out during the import process. 
 grails install-plugin jquery 
 grails install-plugin resources

Comment: Thanks Vinny, for the quick answer. I just got finished installing the jquery plugin - although it said TERMINATED. I hope that does not mean it failed. There were no error or warning messages. I will next try the grails install-plugin resources if it still does not work.

Comment: This "seems" to have fixed the javascript problem. But I will keep this open until I can check it out further tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, glad you are moving forward!

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of where I should look in order to solve this error - it makes no sense to me ... it occurs when I try to add to a table on a button click - - - - - **Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering your page the following have not been rendered: [defer]**

Comment: I'll post this as a separate question.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Vinny. I am and I did import it. After searching this out, the problem was that I, well, I had to add calls to `r:layoutResources`. This is what I did and it seems to work now ... after g:layoutHead I added `<r:layoutResources disposition="defer"/>`. Then after g:layoutBody I added `<r:layoutResources/>`